# Link to shipping tracking from website?

Tags: php, e-commerce

When a customer views an order. We show them the carrier and the tracking number. But based on this information is there a way to generate a link directly to the tracking page for that carrier/shipment?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends on the carrier.

fedex you can track with http://www.fedex.com/Tracking?action=track&language=english&cntry_code=us&initial=x&tracknumbers=**trackingnumber**

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely; I would think your biggest obstacle would be getting the proper format for the link to display.

Here's what we use for UPS; it's C#, but there must be something comparable in php:

hypTracking.Text = TrackingNumber;

hypTracking.NavigateUrl = string.Format("http://wwwapps.ups.com/etracking/tracking.cgi?InquiryNumber1={0}&track=Track&TypeOfInquiryNumber=T", TrackingNumber);

wrap that in a switch statement (say show one format for UPS, another for FedEx, and another for USPS) and you should be all set.